# pass values in js function using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This the javascript code that i found on net to show meter reading.

```
<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Wijmo CSS and script -->
    <link type="text/css" href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/aristo/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet" title="metro-jqueryui" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- KnockoutJS for MVVM-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/knockout.wijmo.js"></script>
```

**this their function**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- when document loads, create ViewModel, and apply bindings-->
<!-- Create ViewModel-->
    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.val = ko.observable(50);
        self.min = ko.observable(0);
        self.max = ko.observable(100);
    };

<!-- Bind ViewModel-->
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var vm = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
</script>



<div class="container"> 
    <div class="header"> 
        <h2> 
            Overview</h2> 
    </div> 
    <div class="main demo"> 
        <!-- Begin demo markup -->
        <p> 
        </p>
```

I wanted to pass value from here, by making the input type hidden using php.

```
        <div data-bind="wijslider: {value: val}" style="width: 600px;"> 
        </div>
```

Because i have some values generated from the `$_post`. i tried it lots, but could not pass one!! help

Comment: Pass values into what? I'm a little confused here. If you want to pass a value from PHP into a JavaScript function then just `echo` your function call with a value: `<?php echo "<script> someFunction($phpValue); </script>"; ?>`

Comment: by default it takes 50 in meter readings i wanted  to pass values from php function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?if(!$_post) { ?>
    <!-- html --!>
<?else { ?>
    <!-- html --!>
<?} ?>
```

you can also see this [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php